# unable to resolve external module typescript

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I'm trying to build a project, but I keep getting compiler errors which say

***Unable to resolve external module*** and ***Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type***.

I have header file which contains all the typing reference path, but even when I try to reference the path in the same file, it still doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Is there a `module` declared? Are you using an `import` and `require`?

Comment: I got it resolved temporarily, but still looking for a better solution. I'm using `import` and `require` instead of using `module`.

Comment: Some code would be useful.

Comment: You may need to use a `declare module "REQUIREDMODULENAME" { }` inside the definition file though... As @RyanCavanaugh said -- code will be necessary to help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this error when I shouldn't have due to a bug with TypeScript 1.0.0, but was able to resolve it by upgrading to 1.0.1.  Try doing that.  If you still get the error, it's probably a bug in your code.